# bson.errors.InvalidId pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working with mongodb and PyMongo and I want to delete a row by id:

```
_id = "c8c9447c42c82044be595b" #row id in database
result = database.collection.delete_one({"_id": ObjectId(_id)}) #delete one row with the given id
print(result.deleted_count) #1 true, 0 false
```

When I run my code I get the following error message:

```
bson.errors.InvalidId: 'c8c9447c42c82044be595b' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

I already tried to convert my id to hex but it didn't work, still the same error

```
hexlify = codecs.getencoder('hex')
print(':'.join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in 'c8c9447c42c82044be595b'))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try importing the ObjectId first?  Like - from bson.objectid import ObjectId

Comment: yes, I already imported >> from bson import ObjectId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, 'c8c9447c42c82044be595b' is not a valid ObjectId: it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string. You have provided only 22 characters. =)